# Generating function of recurrence sequence

Tags: generating-functions

I have the following recurrence sequence
$$
a_{1} = 0\,,\quad
a_{2} = 1\,,
\qquad\qquad
a_{n}
=
{2 + 2\left(n - 2\right)\, a_{n - 2}
 +
 \left(n - 2\right)\left(n - 1\right)\, a_{n - 1}
 \over
 n\left(n - 1\right)} 
$$

It starts form
$\displaystyle{%
\left\lbrace%
0,\ 1,\ {2 \over 3},\ {5 \over 6},\ {4 \over 5},\ {37 \over 45},\ {52 \over 63},\ {349 \over 420},\ {338 \over 405},\ {11873 \over 14175}
\right\rbrace
}$.

Please help me to find generating function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Consider $A(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n$ the generating function of $(a_n)$. The recursion you are interested in is that, for every $n\geqslant2$,
$$
n(n-1)a_n=2+2(n-2)a_{n-2}+(n-2)(n-1)a_{n-1}.
$$
Can you identify the generating function of $(b_n)$ when $b_n=n(n-1)a_n$? When $b_n=2$? When $b_n=2(n-2)a_{n-2}$? And when $b_n=(n-2)(n-1)a_{n-1}$? Then see what comes out.

Comment: Found it! ((1-E^(-2x)+((2-2x)Ei[2-2x])/E^2)/(1 - x))